# What does AF_TCNMESSAGE (Returned from getaddrinfo() as the value of the ai_family field) mean?

Tags: c, sockets

I've googled for it, but found nothing other than `#define`'s for the constant.

This is happening on an OSX 10.11 machine.

Here's a small reproducer (the host originally came from the hostname() function, there was some issue with using that so that's why it was hardcoded)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

typedef struct addrinfo     ADRINFO;

int main(void)
{
    const char* host = "Romi-Mac-Mini.local";
    const char* port = "1543";
    ADRINFO *aip, hint = { AI_NUMERICSERV, AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP,
        /*addrlen*/0, /*addr*/0, /*canonname*/0, /*next*/0 };
    const int ret = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hint, &aip);
    if (!aip)
    {
        printf("aip is NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ret=%d ai_family=%d\n", ret, aip->ai_family);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On the problematic machine, it outputs
`ret=0 ai_family=30`

Comment: Maybe [Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) Topology Change Notification (TCN) messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol). What are you passing to `getaddrinfo()`... is this something you would expect to see?

Comment: Added some more information to the question (it's actually someone else who found this, haven't reproduced this myself). We're not expecting this, the code really only wants to deal with IPV4/IPV6

Comment: Got me! Might be interesting to see what happens if you explicitly (for test purposes) set `hint.ai_family` to `AF_INET` (or `AF_INET6`), or if you pass `NULL` for the hint. And it'd be worth capturing _exactly_ what's being passed for the node and service parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to get a small reproducer

Comment: I think this question is a bit confused. `AF_TCNMESSAGE` is defined as 30 in the Windows header file `winsock2.h`. But, if the program is running on macOS, that's meaningless – WinSock is a Windows API, doesn't exist on macOS. Whereas, on macOS, `sys/socket.h` defines `AF_INET6` as `30`. Getting `AF_INET6` makes more sense. I think you are mixing up Windows and macOS. AF numbers are platform-specific, the same name (like `AF_INET6`) is a different number on different platforms, so you need to make sure you are looking at the right header files for your platform